# Deleting an Access database in PHP through a query

Tags: php, html, mysql

So basically, i'm working on this exercise for PHP and i'm not exactly the brightest on that topic yet.
I have to create a query that deletes the records of the database and i have no idea how.
My code is:

```
<?php

$dbName='REIZEN.mdb';

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".      realpath($dbName) ."; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM klanten");

echo ('<table border = "1" style="width=100%">');

foreach ($result as $value){

    echo ('<tr>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['KLANTNR']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['VOORNAAM']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['ACHTERNAAM']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['ADRES']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['POSTCODE']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['WOONPLAATS']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['PROVINCIE']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['TELEFOON']);
    echo ('</td>');
    echo ('</tr>');

}

echo ('</table>');

?>
```

how would I be able to send a variable to another page using this format?

Comment: do you have any unique key or primary key value in your table then please tell so i can help you.

Comment: Can you please edit the question because right now it is not clear what you want to do what is not working.

Comment: @Julian hey have you got solution???

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM klanten` selects all the entries in the table, `DELETE  * FROM klanten` will delete them, `DELETE FROM klanten WHERE id = 1` will delete only the entry with id = 1

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary key name is `id` in your table then first you can create delete page link in your html. like below code.

```
 echo ('<td>');
    $path = "delete.php"
    echo ('<a href="'. $path.'?id='.$value['ID'].'">Delete</a>');
    echo ('</td>');
```

And then in delete.php page you can write code like below.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $dbName='REIZEN.mdb';
        $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".      realpath($dbName) ."; Uid=; Pwd=;");
        $result = $db->query("DELETE FROM klanten WHERE id = $id");
        if($result)
        {
            header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php');
        }
    }
```

i hope this will helpful for you.